# CSS Flip card with link doesn't work in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I want to create CSS flip card which 3d rotates on mouse hover. Similar to [one from W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_flip_card). I want to have link on the back side of the card.

No issues with latest Chrome or Firefox. However, in Safari (Version 17.0 (19616.1.27.211.1)) only right hand side of the link is clickable.

[image][image]

Code example: https://jsfiddle.net/poooow/oe3b0swq/

```css
.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #408abf;
  color: white;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: #66bf40;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<h3>Hover over the image below:</h3>
<div class="flip-card">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
      <h1>Front</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <h1>Back</h1>
      <a href="#">This link doesn't work in Safari</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well you didn't put any link in your href...

Comment: its working for me, Version 17.0 (18616.1.27.111.22, 18616)

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able solve this issue by rotating card sides (`.flip-card-front` and `.flip-card-back`) instead of its container (`.flip-card-inner`).

In given example it means to replace

```
.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

with

```
.flip-card-inner:hover .flip-card-front {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-inner:hover .flip-card-back {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
```

I also moved `transition` and `box-shadow` to card side classes.

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/poooow/g0zjt5eL/